# How can I allow a user to always allow my flash app to access the microphone?

Tags: flash, microphone

We've got a flash application which has started displaying some rather irritating behavior.  Every time the user logs into the site, they see a warning dialog from flash asking them if they want to allow our site to access their microphone for recording:

http://www.teragon.org/stuff/SO/naggy-flash.png

Sorry; I can't get my machine to show that dialog in English, but it basically says, "Should (the server name) be allowed to access your webcam and microphone?".  Once the user clicks "Close", everything works as normal.  The problem is, when "Remember" (Kom ihåg) is selected, it only remembers if the user had chosen "allow" or "deny", but the dialog still is shown *every time* they log in.

Is some setting in our flash app preventing this preference from being correctly stored?  How do I make it so that when the user clicks "Remember", then it remembers not to be shown at all?

**Edit**: This behavior was recently introduced, meaning that some time ago, "remember" really meant "remember", but now it asks every time.  I'm not sure whether this is caused by flash 10, or a newer version of our software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bah, how stupid.  The problem was indeed our fault -- a fellow developer had added a call to Security.showSettings() during one module's initialization function, apparently to fix another bug having to do with getting the microphone delay time.  Doing this will show the dialog regardless of what the user had selected for the "remember" checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. It's a security feature of the FlashPlayer to stop rogue developers from being able to access your microphone or web cam without the user knowing.  Could lead to all sorts of dodgy apps out there.

Comment: Was this behavior introduced in flash 10?

Comment: Nope... it has been around for a while... probably sine Adobe gave you access to web cams and microphones which probably dates back to flash 7

Comment: Ah... didn't realise there was a remember feature... not sure why that isn't working

Comment: Ok, because it was *definitely* possible before, but in previous versions of flash, the "remember" button wasn't there.  You had to go into the flash preferences after the app was loaded, click remember, then it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I've never encountered this behaviour so I can only guess as to the reasons. My first hunch is that Flash player considers it to be a different swf each time. That would mean it's not really "forgetting" what you set, but rather not thinking you've approved that specific swf. Maybe looking into what it uses to identify the and link the approval to it could lead to some progress?

Comment: It definitely remembers something -- it at least remembers which of the two options (allow/deny) was selected last time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have your client copy/install the flash to their local drive and circumvent the restriction this way?

Comment: Sorry -- not possible with this app.